# Is the category of $2$-topological quantum field theories locally small?

Tags: category-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

At first, looking at **2TQFT** I see no reason to expect it to be locally small. But we know that **2TQFT** is equivalent to the category of commutative Frobenius algebras **cFA**$_{\mathbb K}$, which is locally small. But is this enough to conclude that **2TQFT** is also locally small? Certainly the skeleton of **2TQFT** is, being isomorphic to **cFA**$_{\mathbb K}$...

I am new to these grounds, so I am a bit unsure of my steps.

Comment: You can prove the more general statement : if $C,D$ are equivalent categories and $C$ is locally small, then so is $D$

Comment: Can You please quote a good reference on these categories

Comment: @magma I used "Frobenius Algebras and 2D Topological Quantum Field Theories" by Joachim Kock. I was very pleased with it.

Comment: Thank you Soap.